# Variable works outside function, inside function give syntax error

Tags: bash, function

I've been trying to get this function to work. I'm on a 17" MacBook Pro Early 2011. Setting all the variables under "else" work great if you run them separately, they also echo properly. For some reason when I put them in the function… I get a syntax error on line 12 and

```
battery ()
{
    BATTERYISPRESENT=`ioreg -l | grep Cycle`
    if [[ $BATTERYISPRESENT != *'Cycle' ]]
    then
        echo "No Battery Present, Probably a desktop Mac."
    else
        BATTERYCYCLES=`system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Cycle Count" | awk '{print $3}'`
        BATTCURRCAP=`pmset -g batt | sed -n '2 p' | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed 's/;//g'`
        BATTERYCHARGESTATUS=`system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Charging" | awk '{ print $2 }'`
        BATTERYISCHARGING=`system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep -A 4 "AC Charger Information" | grep "Connected: " | awk '{ print $2 }'`
        CHARGERISCONNECTED=`system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep -A 4 "AC Charger Information" | grep "Connected: " | awk '{ print $2 }'`
        echo $BATTERYCYCLES
        echo $BATTCURRCAP
        echo $BATTERYISCHARGING
        echo $CHARGERISCONNECTED
}
```

The output reads:

line 12: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

line 18: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Next time that you have a problem with a shell script, you might save some time if you first paste it into [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).  If shellcheck doesn't solve your problem (or you don't understand shellcheck's error messages), then come to SO.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I did that, but I don't have enough SO cred for it to matter yet… and I don't see a way to up vote a comment…

Answer (score 1):

A `fi` upon you — you're missing the `fi` at the end of the `else`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This fixed it.